# Состаной PK в Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

Есть таблица **Teacher**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`department` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  .................
```

есть таблица **Teacher**:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`teacher` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  ......................
```

так же таблица **Rate** для связи между преподователем и кафедрой.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`rate` (
  `teacher_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `rate` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teacher_id`, `department_id`),
  .........................
```

Но в ней есть еще поле `rate`. Как мне правильно создать сущность для Таблицы `Rate`, что-бы там был составной Primary Key.

Нашел такое решение у индусов.
Но это не совсем, то

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "rate")
    public class Rate {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable = false)
        private Teacher teacher;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
        private Department department;
        @Id
        private Long id = teacher.getId() + department.getId();
        private Double rate;
    }
```

Помогите составить правильную сущность. Может она вообще не должна быть сущностью? Но, как мне тогда получать поле **rate**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Embeddable
public class RateId {
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    public Long teacherId;
    @Column(name = "department_id")
    public Long departmentId;
}

@Entity
public class Rate {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RateId id;

    private Double rate;
}
```